Linux chmod o+x does not allow me to traverse directory if I don't have self or group access
The permissions on a directory are drwxr--r-x.  I am not the owning user, but I am a member of the group that owns the directory, although that group is not given access.  As a member of :other", why do I get permission denied when I try to cd into that directory?

In short: being a member of the group, you are not a member of the "other".

This prior question and answer completely answers my current question.  Thanks much!
